# jQuery SlideToggle Google Maps Issue

Tags: jquery, google-maps, accordion, slidetoggle

I've read other similar threads but nothing with a question / response which helps make it simple enough to understand what I need to do. I'm using jQuery version 1.7 which possibly explains why some of the code posted in other questions is dissimilar.

Google maps loads in a slideToggle'd div with the center point offset to the North West and not visible relative to the portion of the map which is displayed when the div is toggled open. I'm trying to get a very simple map to display, nothing fancy.

```
jQuery(".toggle").click(function () {
    // check the visibility of the next element in the DOM
        jQuery(this).next().slideToggle(); // slide it down
});
```

My jQuery knowledge is limited, but I understand I need to force the iframe to load after the div is toggled. I just don't know how to achieve this! The HTML / PHP code is as below.

```
<span class="toggle">
View Map // with some CSS
</span>

<div id="maps" class="ui-helper-hidden">
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=<?php echo $latitude;?>,<?php echo $longitude;?>&amp;aq=&amp;t=m&amp;z=13&amp;output=embed&key=123456789"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: I think it will load right away already.. so all you have to do is hide/show the div

Comment: @wirey It loads but the marker is offset to the North and West, not centred

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to look at loading the map dynamically using JavaScript and the Maps API. In this process you'll create a center point object which can then be reused to reset the center of the map in the toggle callback function. Something like this should work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        // create a center
        var c = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8790, 151.2064);

        //create map options object
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 14,
            center: c,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('maps'), mapOptions);

        $(".toggle").click(function () {
            // check the visibility of the next element in the DOM
            $(this).next().slideToggle(300, function(){
                google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize"); // resize map
                map.setCenter(c); // set the center
            }); // slide it down

        });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks James but I'm still struggling with this at the moment - all slidetoggle divs working with the exception of the one with the 'maps' ID

Comment: Just the maps div not expanding / sliding down. I now have the code:
<span class="toggle" id="toggler">
  <h2>Location Map</h2>
</span>
  <div id="maps" class="ui-helper-hidden">
<iframe id="googlemap" width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=<?php echo $latitude;?>,<?php echo $longitude;?>&amp;aq=&amp;t=m&amp;z=13&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
</div> I probably don't need the iframe but the div is not expanding - you can briefly see the top of something but not fully

Comment: I'm sure that any <div> you add a map to dynamically with JavaScript must start with fixed css dimensions. So the CSS for your map div should be something like: #maps { height:350px;width:425px; display:none; }

Comment: Fantastic thankyou it is now working. Thanks so much. Could I ask please, how would you adapt the jQuery if I want to load the map in a child div of the #maps div, the child div having ID = "googlemaps"? I want to use the #maps div to load the slider, but the map to appear in the child div. Extra part to the question but it would be really useful to have the info here in one place for jQuery noobs like me :-)

Comment: I don't think you should have to change the jQuery too much, just the css and html layout. Add a child div the with the ID 'googlemaps'. Use the css - #maps { display:none; }, #googlemaps { height:350px;width:425px; }, then change the JavaScript to load the map in the new div - document.getElementById('googlemaps'). See if that works and then have a play around, best way to learn :)