# Google map API doesn't display correctly jQuery slideToggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I put Google Map inside a div, and made a slideToggle onto the div.
the Google Map doesn't display correctly.

[image]

Once the div expanded, it doesn't look right like the map below

Please check the code on **[jsFiddle Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/zCHr2/)**

```
<div class="click">
  <div class="hide">
    <div id="map" style="width:300px;height:140px;"></div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery SlideToggle Google Maps Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733482/jquery-slidetoggle-google-maps-issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wait until the map is loaded by adding an event listener for `idle`.  This event will fire once the map is fully loaded and ready.

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
    $('.hide').hide();
});
```

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uZbDF/).

EDIT:

For anyone with a similar problem, [here is the updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uZbDF/1/) with the map positioned offscreen so it remains hidden without using `display:none`.

Comment: Thanks! The map has to be loaded first? As the page looks bit odd at the first open.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately if it has `display:none` the marker won't load.  However there is probably a way to hide it with positioning so you don't have to see the map pop open at first, you might want to check this answer out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4700611/1091751.

Comment: I don't quite understand from that answer, I don't think `position: absolute; left: -10000px;` works with `slideToggle` ? is that right? Thanks

Comment: offscreen is a nice solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you need to wait until map finished render then you set hide a map
because map div was toggle when div on hiding and that make map looking wrong location
init function should look like this

```
function initialize() {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(48.89376,2.33742); 
    var settings = {
    zoom: 15,
      center: latlng,
      disableDefaultUI: true,
        zoomControl: true,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), settings);
  var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
    position:latlng,
  });

  marker.setMap(map);

  // on map idle set div hide
  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
      $('.hide').hide();
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if I enable "hide", it doesn't work.

Comment: thanks for the updated answer, there is a bit issue, it really depends on how fast the pageload is. Is there a better way to fix way?