# google map api with jQuery slideToggle callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

Acutally i've asked the same question

> I put Google Map inside a div, and made a slideToggle onto the div.
>   the Google Map doesn't display correctly.
>   [Google map API doesn't display correctly jQuery slideToggle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18393628/google-map-api-doesnt-display-correctly-jquery-slidetoggle)

but I think this question is closer to the answer, I put everything in slideToggle callback;

```
$this.next('.hide').slideToggle(function initialize(){

}
```

Please view the code on [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/aA9Vq/)

If you open all 3 maps down, and then drag the map a bit and "click" to make it slidedown, you will see the other two are refreshed as well. The issue at the moment is that, all 3 maps refresh together not just itself when slideup or down.

If someone could help? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There wasn't any reference to the element triggering the `slideToggle` function in your code, so it was forced to execute the same thing every time you run the function.

This should work: http://jsfiddle.net/aA9Vq/1/

The major change I did was to change the map ID depending of the context (`this`) of the `slideToggle` function.